# how to use beautifulsoup and regular expression to get IP address from a proxy website

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to use Beautifulsoup and regular expressions to get the IP address from the website (http://www.gatherproxy.com/).

By inspecting the website, I saw that the IP address existing in the following format:

```
<tr class="proxy 149-56-34-94-225F" prx="149.56.34.94:8799" time="2017-03-29T15:42:33Z" type="Transparent" country="United States" port="8799" tmres="797"><td>2m 54s ago</td><td>149.56.34.94</td><td><a>

<tr class="proxy 138-68-180-44-1FB6" prx="138.68.180.44:8118" time="2017-03-29T15:42:32Z" type="Elite" country="United States" port="8118" tmres="47"><td>3m 25s ago</td><td>138.68.180.44</td><td><a>
```

So I am using the following code to get each tag

```
soup.find_all(name='tr',attrs={'class':re.compile(r"proxy [0-9a-zA-Z]+-[0-9a-zA-Z]+-[0-9a-zA-Z]+-[0-9a-zA-Z]+-[0-9a-zA-Z]+")})
```

But the output is nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print the contents of your request from that website, you'll notice that the rows are being generated via Javascript.

Here's an example of that:

`gp.insertPrx({"PROXY_CITY":"","PROXY_COUNTRY":"France","PROXY_IP":"149.202.191.205","PROXY_LAST_UPDATE":"3 1","PROXY_PORT":"C38","PROXY_REFS":null,"PROXY_STATE":"","PROXY_STATUS":"OK","PROXY_TIME":"524","PROXY_TYPE":"Transparent","PROXY_UID":null,"PROXY_UPTIMELD":"4152/393"});`

For this step you don't need BeautifulSoup, you can regex the contents directly.

Like this:

```
import re
import requests
import json

result = requests.get("http://www.gatherproxy.com").content
matches = re.findall(r'gp\.insertPrx\(([^(]*)\);', str(result))

for match in matches:
    _object = json.loads(match)
    print (_object["PROXY_IP"])
```

Which outputs:

> 104.156.226.80
>
> 52.32.220.134
>
> 138.68.184.128
>
> ...

Comment: Thanks Zroq! Your code works perfectly.  Do u have any idea why my previous code doesn't work??

Comment: The `tr` that you were trying to find are generated via javascript, which BeautifulSoup can't parse. You can use `selenium`for that kind of things.